# Highlight line in plot

Tags: plotting, legending, interactive

I have a plot with many functions. Some of the functions overlap. In Maple, when you plot functions with legends, you can just click on the legend and it highlights the corresponding line. Does something similar exist in Mathematica?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### SetterBar

```
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; 5]]; 

Dynamic[Legended[
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[i Sin[i x], {i, 1, 5}]], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[Table[{colors[[i]], Thin}, {i, 5}],
      {Alternatives @@ n, 2} -> Thickness[.01]]], 
  SetterBar[Dynamic[n], Table[i -> 
    Grid[{{Pane[Style[Sin[i x], 16, Bold, "Panel", Opacity[1], colors[[i]], 
          Background -> Opacity[0]], ImageSize -> {60, 30}], 
        Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]], 
         Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 40]}}], {i, 1, 5}], 
   Appearance -> "Vertical"]]]
```

[image]

### TogglerBar

Replace `SetterBar` above with `TogglerBar`:

[image]

In versions prior to version 11., we can also use

```
Dynamic[Plot[Evaluate[Table[i Sin[i x], {i, 1, 5}]], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[Table[{colors[[i]], Thin}, {i, 5}], 
      {Alternatives @@ n, 2} -> Thickness[.01]], 
  PlotLegends -> SetterBar[Dynamic[n], Table[i -> 
      Grid[{{Pane[Style[Sin[i x], 16, Bold, "Panel", Opacity[1], colors[[i]], 
           Background -> Opacity[0]], ImageSize -> {60, 30}], 
         Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]], 
          Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 40]}}], {i, 1, 5}], 
    Appearance -> "Vertical"]]]
```

to get the same result (Similarly, for `TogglerBar`).

Comment: That is awesome!!! Thanks kglr. I appreciate it. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Karim, my pleasure. Thank you  for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: On my system, using Mathematica 11.2 under macOS, the setter and toggle bars are arrayed horizontally, rather than, as your images show, vertically. What's wrong?

Comment: @murray, i am using version 9 on windows 10. I just  confirmed the same issue on version 11 on Wolfram Cloud. A workaround is to use `Legended` instead of `PlotLegends`: ...

Comment: ... that is, `Dynamic[Legended[Plot[Evaluate[Table[i Sin[i x], {i, 1, 5}]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle ->  ReplacePart[Table[Thin, {5}], Thread[ n -> Thickness[.01]]]],TogglerBar[Dynamic[n], Table[i -> Grid[{{Pane[
     Style[Sin[i x], 16, Bold, "Panel", Opacity[1], colors[[i]], 
      Background -> Opacity[0]], ImageSize -> {60, 30}], 
     Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]], 
       Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 40]}}], {i, 1, 5}], 
    Appearance -> "Vertical"]
]]` works as expected.