# Another way to highlight plot lines

Tags: plotting, legending

Example data:

```
data = <|"France" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.5, "12" -> 101.0, 
     "13" -> 101.5, "14" -> 102.3, "15" -> 102.8, "16" -> 103.1`, 
     "17" -> 103.3, "18" -> 103.7, "19" -> 103.9, "20" -> 104.1, 
     "21" -> 104.6, "22" -> 105.0|>, 
   "Spain" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.4, "12" -> 100.7, 
     "13" -> 100.5, "14" -> 100.1, "15" -> 99.9, "16" -> 99.9, 
     "17" -> 100.1, "18" -> 100.4, "19" -> 101.0, "20" -> 101.8, 
     "21" -> 102.0, "22" -> 102.0|>, 
   "Mean" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.2, "12" -> 100.3, 
     "13" -> 100.2, "14" -> 100.4, "15" -> 100.2, "16" -> 100.0, 
     "17" -> 100.0, "18" -> 100.0, "19" -> 99.9, "20" -> 100.1, 
     "21" -> 100.0, "22" -> 99.7|>, 
   "Italy" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.3, "12" -> 100.3, 
     "13" -> 100.8, "14" -> 102.7, "15" -> 102.7, "16" -> 102.5, 
     "17" -> 102.4, "18" -> 102.2, "19" -> 101.1, "20" -> 100.8, 
     "21" -> 100.1, "22" -> 99.7|>, 
   "Portugal" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.0, "12" -> 99.7, 
     "13" -> 99.2, "14" -> 98.6, "15" -> 98.1, "16" -> 97.8, 
     "17" -> 97.5, "18" -> 97.3, "19" -> 97.2, "20" -> 97.4, 
     "21" -> 97.4, "22" -> 97.9|>, 
   "Greece" -> <|"10" -> 100.0, "11" -> 100.0, "12" -> 99.7, 
     "13" -> 99.0, "14" -> 98.3, "15" -> 97.7, "16" -> 97.0, 
     "17" -> 96.8, "18" -> 96.6, "19" -> 96.5, "20" -> 96.4, 
     "21" -> 96.0, "22" -> 94.1|>|>;
```

My question is a follow-up on this answer by @kglr:

[Highlight line in plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164063/highlight-line-in-plot)

Borrowing from it with some changes:

```
ClickPlot[dt_] :=
 
 DynamicModule[{black, check, color, lands, length, pal, pos, years},
  
  lands = Keys @ dt;
  years = ToExpression @ Keys[dt[[1]]];
  length = Length @ lands;
  
  pal = Flatten[{#, #}] &[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]];
  color = Table[i -> {pal[[i]], Thickness[0.0025]}, {i, length}];
  black = Table[i -> {Black, Thin}, {i, length}];
  check = Table[i -> Pane[Style[lands[[i]], "Panel"]], {i, length}];
  
  Dynamic @ Column[{
     ListPlot[dt,
      DataRange -> MinMax[years],
      Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {years, None}},
      GridLines -> {years, Automatic},
      ImageSize -> 600,
      Joined -> True,
      LabelingFunction -> None,
      PlotHighlighting -> "Ball",
      PlotLabels -> Automatic,
      PlotStyle -> Values[<|black, KeyTake[pos] @ color|>]
      ],
     
     Panel @ CheckboxBar[
       Dynamic[pos], check,
       Method -> "Active",
       Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 7}
       ]
     }]
  ]
```

Highlight France, Spain and Italy:

```
ClickPlot[data]
```

[image]

I would like to omit the `CheckboxBar` and click the `PlotLabels` instead. This
should be extremely difficult to achieve. But maybe it would be possible to link the
plot lines to `Button` - wrappers. (See documentation for `ListPlot`, `Details and Options`).

Then, by clicking one or more lines (possibly at the right end points), one would get the highlight effects as shown above.

Comment: related Q/A: [Plot many curves on the same graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239611/125)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can replace the `PlotLabels` with `Button`s:

```
ClickPlot[dt_] := 
 DynamicModule[{black, check, color, lands, length, pal, pos = {}, 
   years}, lands = Keys@dt;
  years = ToExpression@Keys[dt[[1]]];
  length = Length@lands;
  pal = Flatten[{#, #}] &[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]];
  color = Table[i -> {pal[[i]], Thickness[0.0025]}, {i, length}];
  black = Table[i -> {Black, Thin}, {i, length}];
  Dynamic@ListPlot[
    dt,
    DataRange -> MinMax[years],
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {years, None}},
    GridLines -> {years, Automatic},
    ImageSize -> 600,
    Joined -> True,
    LabelingFunction -> None,
    PlotLabels -> Table[
      With[{i = i}, 
       Button[Keys[dt][[i]], 
        pos //= If[MemberQ[pos, i], DeleteCases[i], Append[i]], 
        Appearance -> "Frameless"]],
      {i, length}
      ],
    PlotStyle -> Values[<|black, KeyTake[pos]@color|>],
    PlotLegends -> None
    ]
  ]

ClickPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, thank you. But: I click France - ok. Then I click Portugal - also ok. Now I click Portugal again - Not ok, because all highlights are gone. To continue from this point I have to restart ClickPlot.

Comment: @eldo Should be fixed now

Comment: Perfect - and much more than I hoped for :)

Comment: @Lukas Lang: Would it possible to hide all the "unselected" plots but keep their `PlotLegends` on the right so that one can choose from?

Comment: You could replace `Black` with `Opacity[0]`

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way to turn plot labels into `Toggler`s:

```
ClearAll[togglerLabels]

togglerLabels[Dynamic[y_], vals_, labels_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Table[With[{i = i}, 
   Setter[Dynamic[MemberQ[y, i], BoxForm`TogglerBarFunction[y, i] &], 
     {True}, labels[[i]], o, Appearance -> None, Alignment -> Center]], 
  {i, vals}]
```

***Example:***

```
blah =.
{togglerLabels[Dynamic[blah], {1, 2, 3}, {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"}], 
 Dynamic[blah]}
```

[image]

Use `togglerLabels[...]` as the setting for `PlotLabels`:

```
ClearAll[clickPlot]

clickPlot[dt_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DynamicModule[{pos = {}, lands = Keys @ dt, length = Length @ dt, 
   years = ToExpression @ Keys[dt[[1]]], 
   pal = Flatten[{#, #}] &[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]], black, color},
  color = Table[i -> {pal[[i]], Thickness[0.0025]}, {i, length}];
  black = Table[i -> {Black, Thin}, {i, length}];
  Dynamic @ ListPlot[dt, o,
    DataRange -> MinMax[years],
    FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {years, None}},
    GridLines -> {years, Automatic},
    PlotLabels -> 
      togglerLabels[Dynamic@pos, Range[length], 
       MapThread[Style[##, 16] &] @ {lands, Values @ color}],
    PlotStyle -> Values[<|black, KeyTake[pos] @ color|>],
    PlotHighlighting -> {"Ball"},Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
    Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> None, LabelingFunction -> None]]


clickPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: `togglerLabels` is essentially `TogglerBar` with formatting removed to get a list of togglers.

Comment: I tried the above code and I got an error `Unknown option PlotHighlighting in ListPlot`. My MMA version is 13.1.

Comment: [PlotHighlighting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html) is introduced in version 13.3.0

Comment: I knew I was forgetting a control type that is perfect for this... Very nice!

Comment: @kglr: The mean of time-series plots across countries remains unchanged even if we change the number of selected countries. This is because the mean is taken over the entire sample of countries. In fact, it will be more consistent with the plot style if the mean of the selected time-series is calculated. I know this is not what is requested by the question, though. A point to consider for revision.

Comment: very good point.