# Matching Curves to Legend Names in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

When I display multiple curves on the same ListPlot, I differentiate them using various colors and a legend. However, when the number of curves increases, the legend becomes less effective, as the colors aren't easily distinguishable. While I can click on each curve to select it, I'm unsure how to match the curve to its respective name in the legend. Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: closely related Q/A: [Plot many curves on the same graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/239609/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**
You could try `PlotHighlighting` (since 13.3)

```
data = Accumulate @ RandomInteger[{-4, 4}, {10, 10}];

ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotHighlighting -> Directive[Purple, Thick],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Automatic, Thickness[0.002]]]
```

Now, as you hoover over the plot area, the line nearest to the mouse pointer turns `Purple` and `Thick` and is easily distinguishable.

**This answer also works for versions prior to 13.3:**

[Highlight line in plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164063/highlight-line-in-plot)

If your data is organized as `Association` of `Association`s or `Dataset`:

[Another way to highlight plot lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288931/another-way-to-highlight-plot-lines)

**2.** Labeling your data might also help:

```
ListLinePlot[
 AssociationThread[ToString /@ Range[10] -> data],
 PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**3**. And you should also have a look at `Tooltip`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have 13.1

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Finally Tooltip is the best option since Labeling is not very useful when there are about 100 curves. I wonder why Tooltip is not activated by default...

Answer (score 2):

For a large number of curves use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) with a [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) to selectively display any or all of the curves.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = Accumulate@RandomInteger[{-4, 4}, {10, 10}];

labels = Subscript["curve", #] & /@ Range[Length[data]];

colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

{min, max} = MinMax[Flatten[data]];

Manipulate[
 sel = If[FreeQ[sel, None],
   If[FreeQ[sel, All],
    Sort@sel, Range[Length[data]]],
   {}];
 ListLinePlot[
  Tooltip @@@ Transpose[{data[[sel]], labels[[sel]]}],
  PlotRange -> {min, max},
  PlotStyle -> colors[[sel]],
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic,
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", If[Length[sel] > 5, 2, 1]}]],
 {{sel, Range[Length[data]]},
  Join[Thread[Range[Length[data]] -> labels], {None, All}],
  ControlType -> TogglerBar},
 TrackedSymbols :> {sel}]
```

[image]